# How to search nested array with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I am trying to filter an array and only return the objects that have a role of 'admin'.

However, the field that contains the role is nested under multiple levels in the array. What is the correct MongoDB syntax in order to grab the value?

Below is an example of what it looks like. It goes roles > Company Name > 0 > **value**.

```
        _id:"Pgxoyv"
        createdAt:"Fri Aug 18 2017"
        roles: {} 1 key
             Company Name: [] 1 item
                  0:"admin"
```

I've tried filtering but the space between "Company Name" is throwing errors as well. Any help would be appreciated. Here is what I tried so far, but this returned no value:

```
Meteor.users.find({
            roles: 'admin'
        }).fetch();
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the actual json document you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Meteor.users.find({
        roles.companyName: 'admin'
    }).fetch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
{
    "roles": {
        "Company Name": [ 
            "admin"
        ]
    }
}
```

you can do a

```
Meteor.users.find({"roles.Company Name": "admin"})
```